# How can we write nCr in Theta and Big Oh notation in the simplest way?

Tags: big-o, combinatorics

> How can we write **nCr** in Theta and Big Oh Notation in the simplest way?

For example for small rs we have:
**nC2 = n * (n-1) / 2 = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)**
**nC3 = n * (n-1) * (n-2) / 6 = Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)**

For arbitrary **n** and **r** we have: **nCr = Θ(n! / (r! * (n-r)!))**
Is that possible to write **nCr** in a simpler way?
For example can we write **nCr = Θ(n! / max(n,n-r)!)** or any thing else and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `r` is a constant you know, just simplify `nCr` to something like `Θ(n^r)`.

If `r` is an other parameter of something you want to describe, just write `Θ(nCr)`. it is just what you are doing for graph algorithms where you write `Θ(n*m)` where `n` is the number of nodes and `m` is the number of edges, even if you could bound this by `O(n^3)`.

If `r` can be anything and you cannot control it, use the worst case `r = n/2` and try to simplify it using Stirling approximation.